# what is better approach to use slice or splice when remove element from an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Because of high data volume i have set array `$scope.event` size limit so when it reaches `BufferLimit` remove first item from an array and add latest item to array. What is best approach to use `slice` or `splice` in terms of high data volume when you remove add item ?

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];
    function safelyAdd(element) {
        if (totalReceived > Bufferlimit && $scope.event.length) {

            $scope.event = $scope.event.slice(1); //delete first element in $scope.event

            totalReceived -= $scope.event[0].messageSize; //total message size minus deleted message size
            console.log('totalReceivedBytes', totalReceived);
            // $scope.event =[];//reset array if max size reached..
            console.log('$scope.event', $scope.event)
        }
        console.log('$scope.event.length', $scope.event.length);

            $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..

    }
```

Comment: This is largely (if not entirely) opinion-based; it's worth noting, I suppose, that `slice()` returns a new Array whereas `splice()` modifies the Array in place, and returns an Array of the removed elements: https://jsfiddle.net/4hs0Lvy6/ Note that this choice seems, at best, to be a micro-optimisation, so the best approach is almost certainly to remain consistent with your - or your team's - usual programming practices.

Comment: Splice is more performance improved but not pure function, as it mutates original.

Comment: yeah i have performance issue we are getting almost 10k plus messages in a minute , so what is better in that case ?

Comment: @hussain: why not try both, with a simulated set of messages and use whichever you feel is best, and more performant, in your use-case? I'd be interested in the metrics but, as asked, this is opinion-based.

Comment: i tried slice first that froze tha browser at buffeLimit splice looks good in terms of performance

Comment: is there any better approach i can do rather than slice or splice ?

Comment: another thing is in slice i always see last item on screen because that was the last element in array but in splice it changes the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That completely depends on your requirements:

1. The `splice()` method returns the removed item(s) in an array and `slice()` method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object.
2. The `splice()` method changes the original array and `slice()` method doesn't change the original array.
3. You can insert item in the array while using `splice()` but `slice()` only removes item.

Comment: how can i completely remove item from an array ? i see both `slice` and `splice` returns something , we are talking about alot of data lets assume 1000 messages per minute. what you think is better in that case ?

Comment: If you just want to remove items only without modifying the original array then slice() should be the choice.

Comment: i was using slice and i see browser get frozen at `BufferLimit` because heavy slicing and adding new item.

Comment: Did you try with splice()? You can use this but it changes the original array.

Comment: what you mean changes original array ?

Comment: splice() mutates or changes the array on which they are implemented.

Comment: is it possible to use splice and add new item at the end of array ?

Comment: Yes you can, that is one of the advantages of using splice()

Comment: but using splice its not adding new item at the end of array ?

Comment: var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon'];

myFish.splice(2, 0, 'drum'); // insert 'drum' at 2-index position
// myFish is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "sturgeon"]

Comment: so you think by using your approach of splice new item will be last item  in the array, in my case new item is pushed outside if statement

Comment: In that way you can append only at the index you are removing item....not in the last.

Comment: what you think if i use `shift()` ?

Comment: I think we were taking about slice() vs splice() here. Anyway, I think you can insert item at last index with splice() like this: var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon']; myFish.splice(myFish.length, 0, 'drum'); 
// insert 'drum' at last-index position // myFish is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "drum"]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using splice, as it mutates the array you're working with, whereas slice doesn't alter the array - it creates a new one.

The differences in speed etc are most likely unseen by the user (unless it's huge), in this case splice would be more useful.

```
$scope.event.splice(0, 1);
```

More information here;

[Link](https://ariya.io/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice)

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on your requirement.In angularJs we always use data binding, so its always good to use splice so that UI reflects immediately.But if you are using slice, it returns a new array and again, you need to put it in scope array to reflect in UI. I would recommend if angularjs and there is no dependency on same array, go with splice.